# Referencing Minified Content in Asp.Net / MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, minify

We have  dozens of scripts referenced in our web pages (MVC).

To optimize the site if i minify and merge all scripts into one file , do i need to update those dozen references in each webpage with the new combined file ?

If so is there a tool to automate the script references in all web pages with the new file or one has to do it manually ?

Any reference in this regard will be helpfull.

thanks

Comment: This library is easy to use for creating bundles and minifying. Visit the project page for more info https://nuget.org/packages/RxLoader/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **bundling**

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Though this is an MVC 4 feature, you can use this in MVC 3 as well.

*More reference:*

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetandvisualstudio_topic5.aspx)

[Nuget Path](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0)